# How do I include files with pyinstaller?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, compiler-errors, pyinstaller

I have made a program with python 3.7 using tkinter aswell. Since I am using external pictures I need to include them when I compile everything to one exe. I have tried doing `--add-data "bg.png;files"` but I still get this error:

> _tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "files/bg.png": no such file or directory

Here is the code:

```
image = PhotoImage(file="files/bg.png")
w = image.width()
h = image.height()
x = 316
y = 246
mainGui.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (w, h, x, y))
panel = Label(mainGui, image=image)
panel.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')
```

What am I doing wrong? I have tried `--add-binary` as well, adding the file to my spec file. Seriously can't figure this out!

Comment: Maybe [this recipe](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-Collect-Data-Files) is useful?

Comment: 1. Which OS are you using? 2. Are you using -F or --one-file option when compiling with pyinstaller?

Comment: Hi Kamal, I am running Windows 10. I have tried both -F and --one-file.

Comment: Please try once without -F or --one-file option. For --one-file option, you need to follow add code like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13790741/5319738)

Comment: Same thing unfortunately :/

Comment: The files do get included, I can see the size getting larger when I tell pyinstaller to include them. But for some reason my actual program can't find them!

Comment: Please share your code as per guidelines here https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Here is the code from my python script where I call my file:

`image = PhotoImage(file="files/bg.png")`
    `w = image.width()`
    `h = image.height()`
    `x = 316`
    `y = 246`
    `mainGui.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (w, h, x, y))`
    `panel = Label(mainGui, image=image)`
    `panel.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')`

It is located in the same directory as the script, so when I run it in PyCharm it all works like it should. But when I compile it in pyinstaller, with or without -F or --onefile, it doesnt find it

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Sorry, I thought that only -F/--one-file makes such behavior, but looks like any bundling with pyinstaller needs such changes.

You need to change your code like this, as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile/13790741#13790741):

```
import sys

if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    image = PhotoImage(file=os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, "files/bg.png"))
else:
    image = PhotoImage(file="files/bg.png")
```

And then bundle it with pyinstaller like this:

```
pyinstaller --clean -y -n "output_name" --add-data="files\bg.png;files" script.py
```

Comment: You are a legend, thank you soooo much! Works flawless!

Comment: Just a small update. I have some sound aswell and I tried adapting those lines into my winsound.Playsound, but it doesn't seem to take it the same way as tkinter does.

winsound.PlaySound(os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, "files/bgm.wav", winsound.SND_LOOP + winsound.SND_ASYNC))

Do you know how to formulate it so python understand it? @Kamal

Don't really understand how I can use the 'code' function here on stackoverflow, so it hope its possible to read it.

Comment: You have closed the parenthesis of `os.path.join` at wrong position, try: `winsound.PlaySound(os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, "files/bgm.wav"), winsound.SND_LOOP+winsound.SND_ASYNC)`. And check [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77485/code-formating-in-comments) for formatting help.

Comment: That did it, thanks for all the help @Kamal! I started programming a week ago, feels good to learn new stuff all the time!

Comment: Stumbled here by chance, but this solved my problem: "How to make the Python script auto-determine if it's running in the regular interpreter (i.e. *script.py*) or from a package created with PyInstaller (*script.exe*)?

I actually discovered that the *frozen* attribute is set to True in the .exe version, while in the .py it is == False.

Thank you so much!